# @Required annotation in Spring 6 and JDK 20

Tags: java, spring

I am just learning Spring. I am following a tutorial and came across the dependency check, for which I have to use the `@Required` annotation, but I am getting an error, and when I try to search for the package, it’s not showing up. I'm not sure if it’s deprecated. I am using Spring 6 and JDK 20.

```java
@Required
public void setId() {
    this.id =id
}
```

Comment: Ditch the tutorial and find an up-to-date one. `@Required` has been removed quite some time ago already.